# What are the steps needed to convert a video to a Gif in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, gif, video-processing, video-compression

I have a project that involves creating a program that converts a video into a gif. Sounds simple enough if I use OpenCV but I need to organize the bitstream of the gif file myself. I Googled around and I can't find any resources that outline the steps required to achieve this or how to organize the bitstream myself.

I'm assuming the steps I need to do is image compression for each frame but I'm not sure if I still need to use Motion Estimation if I want a smooth Gif in the end.

edit: Just to be clear I need this to be done without using a library that converts the video to a gif for me so moviepy won't work

Comment: @shash678 I've come across that link before, but it still doesn't help me figure out how to layout the bitstream of the gif myself

Comment: any progress with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from moviepy.editor import *

clip = (VideoFileClip("ABCD.mp4")
        .subclip((1,22.65),(1,23.2))
        .resize(0.3))
clip.write_gif("ABCD.gif")
```

**You can download Youtube Video with this command if you have Youtube-dl installed:**

```
youtube-dl 2Jw-AeaU5WI -o ABCD.mp4
```

Comment: So how do I organize the bitstream then?